# Separate Google Analytics Properties On Subdomains

Tags: google-analytics

I've created three websites on one root domain and two subdomains. In Google Analytics I've created three properties and each website has a different Google code snippet.

Do I need to make any configuration changes to the Google Analytics properties for this to work properly? Is there a reporting issue when visitors go between these sites?

Answer (score 2):

If you want seperate reporting for the main domain and it's subdomains, then the seperate GA properties will be fine.

Keep in mind the subdomain traffic will not report as referral traffic to the main domain, and vice versa, together with traffic moving between the subdomains.  This is due to the default behaviour of GA regarding the referral exclusion list.

If you want to share the session and originating referrer information of the site visitors between the main domain and it's subdomains if they move between them via site links or similar, then you'll need to use a single GA property on all domains with cookieDomain set to auto (which it should be configured for by default).

It is also usually handy in the above scenario (using a single GA Property), to create another View and apply a filter to prepend the hostname info to the requestURI info in the GA reports so as to split out the pageview information for each domain/subdomain, rather than the default aggregate pageview reporting.

Comment: I guess my comment was wrong.  I didn't know the referral exclusion list would work like that.  Great answer.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thanks :-)  Referral excl. can be a pita in some cases eg if using different GA Properties to track a domain/subdomains and one wants to see the applic. domains/subdomains as the referrers for the traffic moving between them. Requires further additional JS code if that is the case.